# How to color the selected character with red instead of changing it?

Tags: highlight

In my .vimrc,f5 was binded with CheckMark function to change all `。` into `.`.

```
function! CheckMark()  
    if search('。')  
        let s:line=search('。')  
        execute s:line . "s/。/\./g" 
    endif   
endfunction  

map <F5> :call CheckMark()<CR>
```

How to  color the selected  character `。` with red ,instead of changing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:match` command to do this:

```
:highlight CheckMark ctermfg=red guifg=red
:match CheckMark /。/
```

If you want this highlighting only to occur when you invoke your mapping, you can replace the contents of your `CheckMark()` function with the `:match` command.

See `:help :match` for more details.